# How to mount a host directory with non-root ownership

Tags: docker, mount-point

I use `build-arg` to ensure my container runs with the same UID as my host user:

```
--build-arg UID=$(UID)
```

I am mounting a volume with:

```
-v $(PWD)/packages:/mnt/packages
```

Because I want my container to produce some output into that directory.

The directory belongs to the host user.

But, not matter what I try, the mountpoint in the container belongs to root. I can correct it with sudo in the running container:

```
function correct-mountpoint-permissions () {
  # Hack alert:
  #   When mounting a host volume, it belongs to root, no matter what I do in the host or in the Dockerfile
  #   Here we correct the situation by using sudo. It's not nice, but that's life
  #   Note: the same problem does NOT happen with *named* volumes, but that completely defeats the purpose of
  #   mounting the volume in the first place - which is to produce some output visible on the host.
  #   If I have to start copying from containers to host, mounting volumes offers no benefit
  sudo chown "$USER:$USER" "$PACKAGES"
}
```

But this is just ugly. I should not even need to have sudo installed in the first place, or sudo rights at all in my container.

The alternative is to either mount a named volume, which is difficult to access from the host, or to avoid mounting volumes in the container at all, and just `docker cp` from it when my container has produced the expected output.

Is there a simple way of mounting a **host** volume with the right ownership into a container (which means, not root, but my selected `UID`)

Comment: The scope of a `build-arg` is limited to build time. Your run time environment may or may not have the UID set as you expect.

Comment: @JR.got it. These are private images, to be used on a single host. I use them to automate tasks which need execution in other OS (in this case, download python packages in a different OS than my host OS). UIDs are stable in this use case.

Comment: @volingas - Did you finally do something else other than this hack? I have a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you must be setting a user in your Dockerfile.
Before the user is set , try changing the ownership of the user during the build of the image.

```
RUN chown -R myuser:myuser ${PACKAGES_DIR}
USER myuser
```